# How to retrieve the UNC path instead of mapped drive path from JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser, unc

Just wondering if there is a way to return back the UNC path from a file chosen with JFileChooser.  The file that I would be selecting would reside on a mapped drive that has a UNC path.  Right now, I can only seem to pull back the drive letter of a mapped drive.

Comment: The `JFileChooser` method `getSelectedFile()` returns a `File` which has this information.

Comment: this helped me out quite a bit, although i needed the UNC path of the current machine, rather than a mapped drive.  using 'ipconfig /all' and slicing it up should do the trick.  you should take that edit above and post it as an answer to get cred.  thanks for posting the solution.

Comment: @trashgod: there's some reputation waiting for you here ;P.

Comment: @moonlightcheese: Sorry I overlooked this earlier; thanks to Zecas for the heads-up.

Answer (score 3):

From https://stackoverflow.com/users/715934/tasoocoo

I ended up finding a solution that executes the NET USE command:

```
 filePath = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
 Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process process = runTime.exec("net use");
 InputStream inStream = process.getInputStream();
 InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
 String line = null;
 String[] components = null;
 while (null != (line = bufferedReader.readLine())) {
   components = line.split("\\s+");
    if ((components.length > 2) && (components[1].equals(filePath.substring(0, 2)))) {
      filePath = filePath.replace(components[1], components[2]);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) method [`getSelectedFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile--) returns a [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html), which may have helpful information.

"For Microsoft Windows platforms,…the prefix of a UNC pathname is `"\\\\"`; the hostname and the share name are the first two names in the name sequence."

Comment: @PaulTaylor: I've elaborated above.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented on Gerry's answer, `ShellFolder.getDisplayName` is unreliable because the user can changed the display name to whatever they want.

However the UNC path does seem to be available via `sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder`. This is of course an "internal proprietary API" so no guarantee this will continue to work in future versions of java, but testing against java 1.8.0_31 in Windows 7 I see a `ShellFolderColumnInfo` titled `Attributes` which for network drives appears to include the UNC path as a bare `String`. eg:

```
File networkDrive = new File("G:\");
ShellFolder shellFolder = ShellFolder.getShellFolder(networkDrive);
ShellFolderColumnInfo[] cols = shellFolder.getFolderColumns();
for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    if ("Attributes".equals(cols[i].getTitle())) {
        String uncPath = (String) shellFolder.getFolderColumnValue(i);
        System.err.println(uncPath);
        break; // don't need to look at other columns
    }
}
```

If you go to My Computer in explorer, change to Details view and turn on the "Network Location" column, it appears to match what we get from "Attributes" via the `ShellFolder` API. Not sure where "Attributes" comes from or if it changes in non-english locales.

Comment: Ok the JVM seems to use `IShellDetails::getDetailsOf` to populate `ShellFolderColumnInfo.title` which as stated here can change according to locale:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But msdn also says columns 0/1/2/3 are always Name/Size/Type/Date Modified. Java's ColumnInfo titles match MSDN, but in reality the column values represent DiskLabel/Type/Size/FreeSpace. It may be more portable to directly index the column, ie `String uncPath = (String) shellFolder.getFolderColumnValue(6);`

Comment: Also note that the Size column (1) which really store type could possibly be used I found a local drive reported 'Local Disk' and a network drive reported 'Network Drive'

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is looking for an alternate (and I think simpler) solution,
you can find the information using ShellFolder.getDisplayName(). For example, you can parse the network location of the drive from the string here:

```
System.out.println(ShellFolder.getShellFolder(new File(filePath.substring(0,3))).getDisplayName());
```

This might also be useful:

```
File.listRoots();
```

Comment: This works because windows by default sets the drive label to something like `$SHARENAME (\\$SERVER)` for mapped network drives. However the user is free to change this label to something completely different, so it's unwise to rely on `ShellFolder.getDisplayName` always having this information.