# In Java how do I find actual path of remote filesystem mounted on Windows

Tags: java, nio

On my Windows PC I have my NAS with network path `\\nas` mounted as `Z:\`

Finding the root of a file on the filestore with Java 8

```
Paths.get("Z:\\\\Docs").getRoot();
```

gives me `Z:\`

how do I get `\\nas`

This code is not running as part of the GUI, therefore I do not have access to JFileChooser with currently selected file.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722146/how-to-retrieve-the-unc-path-instead-of-mapped-drive-path-from-jfilechooser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching file and path from network using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991294/fetching-file-and-path-from-network-using-java)

Comment: I would like a standard pure java solution, is there not a way with nio ?

Comment: Hey Paul. Have you tried `toRealPath()`? On Windows that seems to return the network path.

Comment: @hendrik hi, that doesnt seem to work me gives NoSuchFileException

Comment: It only works on existing files. So you could try to list a file from that dir, and then call `toRealPath()` on it.

Comment: Hmm, but Z:\Docs is a real file but also Files.exists(p) returns false, why would that be, am I missing something stupid.

Comment: @Lothar not a duplicate since I do not have a JFileChooser instance

Comment: @hendrik the no such fileexception is some admin/permissions problem I have if run form within Intellij. But if I install as normal I don't get the exception but calling getRealPath() on Z:\ just returns Z:\

Comment: @PaulTaylor Read the answers. The JFileChooser is only the source of the filename, the answers show a couple of ways to get what you need.

Comment: @Lothar yes the ShellFolder answer looks like it will work, (though not ideal as I will have to use reflection to avoid it causing problems if on non-windows env). But my point was that the question is different (even if one of the answers may be the same)